# mutationObserver - how to observe innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

Is it possible to observe innerHTML of node via mutationObserver? I'm trying to use characterData: true, but it does not shoot any callback on content change.
full options list:

```
childList: true,
attributes: true,
characterData: true
```

Comment: What kind of content change?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40195712 for a good answer; including the distinction to textContent

Answer (score 11):

Hi I think you need to add

> subtree: true

in your options list.

Have a look at https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers