# Mutation Observer Not Detecting Text Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mutation-observers

I'm scratching my head as to why MutationObserver doesn't detect text changes done using textContent.

### HTML

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
function mutate(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    alert(mutation.type);
  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('div#mainContainer > p').textContent = 'Some other text.';
  }, 2000);

  var target = document.querySelector('div#mainContainer > p')
  var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
  var config = { characterData: true, attributes: false, childList: false, subtree: true };

  observer.observe(target, config);
});
```

In the above script, the paragraph element's text content clearly changes but MutationObserver doesn't detect it.

However, if you change textContent to innerHTML, you will be alerted that the "characterData" has changed.

Why does MutationObserver detect innerHTML but not textContent?

Here is the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vp8t8x7/

Notice that you'll only get alerted if you change textContent to innerHTML.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's because `textContent` triggers a different [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#MutationObserverInit) than `innerHTML`, and your observer configuration is not configured to observe the changes made by `textContent`.

`textContent` changes the child text node of the target. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) setting `textContent`:

> Setting this property on a node removes all of its children and
> replaces them with a single text node with the given value.

While `innerHTML` changes the the element itself, and its subtree.

So to catch `innerHTML` your configuration should be:

```
var config = { characterData: true, attributes: false, childList: false, subtree: true };
```

While to catch `textContent` use:

```
var config = { characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };
```

Demo:

```js
function mutate(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    alert(mutation.type);
  });
}

  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector('div#mainContainer > p').textContent = 'some other text.';
  }, 1000);
  
  var target = document.querySelector('div#mainContainer > p')
  var observer = new MutationObserver( mutate );
  var config = { characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };

  observer.observe(target, config);
```

```html
<div id="mainContainer">
  <h1>Heading</h1>
  <p>Paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was assuming that using textContent to change text would not trigger mutation observer callback but in firefox it is triggering observer callback while on chrome it is not. Can you please share why this happens?