# How can JS Detect changes in the HTML such as ctr+shift+i input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-input

[Here](https://PressCmdI--chrismwade.repl.co) is a website I am currently developing. As a challenge for the user we are asking them to use ctrl+shift+i to interact with the HTML and change certain elements.

How can Javascript, or html/css detect that they changed that?

i.e.

```
<div>
  <p>This is placeholder text</p>
</div>
```

We want them to change that placeholder text to something specific and then grant them access to a new page.

Comment: Have you debugged and inspected what properties are available on the event, in the case that you hit those key strokes?

Comment: The best I can think of is periodically scanning the content of these elements and seeing if anything has changed

Comment: @Joeri Could you elaborate and put it into code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mutation Observer Not Detecting Text Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195514/mutation-observer-not-detecting-text-change)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Comment: @ItsLogic this sould explain it https://jsfiddle.net/4maLhq5e/2/

Comment: @Joeri that looks conclusive, but because I haven't worked with this before, could you tell me what should go in the '#this_should_change' parameter and if I need to change `document.querySelector`

Comment: `#this_should_change` is the element of which you want users to change the contents. What this does is load the content of that element on page load and periodically check it for changes

Comment: @Joeri thank you, I set an id to changeThis, assigned it to the element, and added it to the script you gave me and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @ItsLogic I'll add it as an answer then so that we can close this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comments, it is possible to load the default content of an element on page load and then periodically scan for changes

```js
window.onload = () => {
  let changeCheck = document.querySelector('#this_should_change'); // get the element
  let oL = changeCheck.innerHTML; // load the default values
  let check = setInterval(() => {
   if (changeCheck.innerHTML !== oL) { // if the values are different from the values on load
     alert("Stuff changed"); // your code
      clearTimeout(check); // clear the interval so that it does not repeat itself
    }
  }, 100); // this will check the element every second
};
```

```html
<p id="this_should_change">
  Foo
</p>
```