# mutationObserver check if textContent changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to observe when the `{{ cart.invoiceNumber}}` textContent changes.
using the options `childList: true, subtree: true` it will detect some changes but not all of them.
and then I have tried the options `characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false`  and this picks up the  `<span id="cartTotal" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: total }} />` but it doesn't recognise when the textContent changes.

How can I use this to observe when the textContent changes?

```
 export function elementReady(selector) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let el = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (el) {resolve(el);}
    new MutationObserver((mutationRecords, observer) => {
      // Query for elements matching the specified selector
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector)).forEach((element) => {
        resolve(element);
        //Once we have resolved we don't need the observer anymore.
        // observer.disconnect();
      });
    })
      .observe(document.documentElement, {
        characterData: false, attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false 
      });
  });
}



 elementReady('#cartTotal').then((someWidget)=>{ console.log(someWidget)});
```

**layout.js**

`<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: cart.invoiceNumber }} />`

Comment: Hope this question can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195514/mutation-observer-not-detecting-text-change

Comment: I'm not sure how to check for textContent in my code, it helps but Im still a bit lost

Comment: Listening to textContent change can be done by modifying the config array. I saw that was mentioned in the accepted answer. But I think to get the new textContent, you'll need to do like how you're doing above: find the element and get its textContent